# How does a force push affect a cloned branch?

Tags: github, branch, git-branch

I was wondering if a branch is cloned from `master`. And now you remove some commits from `master` and force push. Will those commits be deleted on the cloned branch as well?

Answer (score 2):

No: a branch starting from a commit of another branch will still reference that commit, even if that other branch changes (through a forced push) its HEAD.

You might want to rebase your branch on top of the new reset master, if you don't want to continue referencing those old commits.

```
git fetch
# see that origin/master has been reset
git checkout mybranch
git rebase --onto origin/master master myBranch
```

In that scenario, `master` is still locally at the old HEAD (from which you current branch is starting).
`origin/master` has been reset (and is up-to-date after the `git fetch`)

After that, you can reset your own local `master`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

(make sure you don't have any work in progress when doing a `git reset --hard`)